# reverse from log normalized value to the orignal value with python

Tags: python

I have a data frame with 2 columns :

```
Original value  |  Log normalized of the value
```

the *Log normalized value*  is detrmined as follow :

```
def feature_log_normalize(f):
    return np.log(f)
```

I would like to know how can I do to reverse for log normalized value to the original value in python?

Any idea please?

thanks

Comment: exp(log(f)) = f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get it by doing `e^x`
Simply `np.exp(feature_log_normalize(f))` but it should be ceiled to get `int`value

Comment: Thank you for yout help!